# How to totally control json serialization in WCF

Tags: wcf, json, serialization, rest

I need to totally control the json serialization process in my Rest WCF service. I need to substitute the serialization result, that is something similar to:

```
{ foo: 42, bar: 43 }
```

with:

```
myFunc( { foo: 42, bar: 43 } );
```

any ideas?

thanks
m.

Comment: I can't work on client side behavior, see the comment I left to Mikael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue previously, which I solved by returning a memory stream from a WCF service. once you've done that you can set the MIME type manually. this basically allows you to return any result as any MIME type. I think I used this for jsonp. Sorry, but I'm working off my iPad at the moment so I can't provide an example. A quick google search should get you what you need.

Also, I'd recommend using json.net for your serialization...it's much easier to work with than the standard .net serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your own serializer. You inherit from `DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior` and override `CreateSerializer`.

You can see a sample of how it's done in [protobuf.net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net/ServiceModel/ProtoOperationBehavior.cs).

It might be simpler to expand your output object to include a parameter which is the name of the calling function, and then invoking it on the callback on your web page.

```
{ "func": "myFunc", "foo": "42", "bar": "43" }
```

Other helpful links:

- [Post from Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/442969.aspx) from 2008
  which might help you.
- [WCF REST custom ResponseFormat](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e6c7deca-b220-4fa4-ab9d-a9877bba0743)

Comment: thanks. it's not me who need that "myFunc" parameter. It's the clientside framework I'm using (extJS) who need it. 

Basically I'm trying to putting together ExtJs and WCF/Rest. But they seem to be very different in the way they approach the REST/jSon stuffs...

Comment: I added a couple of more links. Basically you need to implement your own serializer which includes the myFunc part. You might can inhert and extend the JavaScriptSerializer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx